# CS1061 errors upon declaring xmlns:self for an XAML in a Vsto Office Addin

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, xaml, vsto

I am new in the .Net world and I am building an Excel Addin (vsto) in C# in VS 2019. I am trying to show some information in a WPF window. In order to do the binding I am defining the `xmlns:self="clr-namespace:DialogWindow"`.

But building the Project soon after as I declare this "xmlns:self", I get a bunch of CS0266 and CS1061 errors at the C# classes which deals with the Excel.

> CS0266 C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to. An explicit
> conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

at

```
currentSheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
```

> CS1061 C# 'object' does not contain a definition for and no accessible
> extension method accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

at

```
currentSheet.Cells[1, 1].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
```

This whole Addin complies and works fine with the WPF components until I add the xmlns:self in declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent hours looking for solutions, but no luck finding one who used WPF in VSTO Office Addin and had this strange issue. As Bizarre as it may sound. The Solution here is to break them into pieces and cast as it suggests. Solution for the above issue is,

```
Excel.Range newRange = (Excel.Range)newWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
newRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
```

**An explicit casting and passing range into another variable.**
What is still strange is that this whole Addin complies and works fine with the WPF components until I add the xmlns:self in declaration for the bindings.
I have no idea it stooped compiling once I added xmlns:self.